# Extract text from MediaWiki XML dump without installation/API

Tags: php, xml, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

**Background**

Suppose I want to extract the parsed content text for all pages/revisions from MediaWiki. Let's consider the huge English Wikipedia.

I can do this by downloading the required data, setting up my own MediaWiki installation and running a loop to call something like:

```
http://localhost/mediawiki/api.php?uselang=en&format=xml&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=
```

This uses the TextExtracts (https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-TextExtracts) extension, which internally actually does something like:

```
http://localhost/mediawiki/api.php?uselang=en&format=xml&action=parse&prop=text&title=
```

**Question**

Now, I do **not** want to use a MediaWiki installation with the MySQL database and all that. But I want to do just what I described using a MediaWiki XML data dump (the huge English Wikipedia XML dump - enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2). Any ideas as to how I can approach this problem?

Looks like all the parsing logic that calls `WikiPage->getContent` and the lot are inside the MediaWiki PHP classes - and they are too tightly coupled for me to take them out (unless I want to spend weeks on it) and write my own script to work on the dump. Are there any scripts that let me do this? My preferred language would be Java but I'm open to options.

Comment: I think something like this might never be possible owing to template issues. :/

Comment: You're right, you'll probably need MediaWiki, or at least an [alternative parser](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers), to deal with the wikitext -> HTML conversion and templates. If it's the MySQL dependency that you don't like, do note that MediaWiki also supports [SQLite](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SQLite), which does not need a separate DB server process like MySQL does.

Comment: It's not about the DB. I didn't completely explain my whole use-case. If I want to do something like distributed processing of the whole dump using Hadoop or something, having a DB server + MediaWiki instance running on each machine on the cluster is a hassle. And having them on just one machine would hit I/O hard and do the opposite of solving my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you can't do the processing on the raw wikitext? That'd be a lot easier, since you could run it straight off the dump. Alternatively, you could maybe run the wikitext -> HTML conversion once on a single machine (or a few machines, if conversion speed is an issue), building your own HTML-in-XML dump, and save that for later processing.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, I actually need to run my operations on the full template-expanded HTML version, exactly like you'd see on a running instance. But hey, I could try that out - run wikitext->HTML conversion on a single machine (I want to avoid the hassle of installing MW and the DBs on multiple machines), save the dump for parallel processing. Not sure whether the performance balance will tip towards my advantage, will know when I try. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Around 2005 I wrote some Python code to convert MW XML into Dict, not sure if it's still functional but could be useful to check if you like Python: [wik2dict](https://code.google.com/p/wik2dict/).

Last year I wrote some CoffeeScript code to turn an XML dump into a Meteor app (and finally Phonegap  app). [mediawikixml2meteor2phonegap](https://github.com/guaka/mediawikixml2meteor2phonegap). This one fails on the English Wikipedia because of its size but it works okay on smaller wikis such as [Hitchwiki](http://hitchwiki.org/).

Both of these projects are far from perfect but they're able to handle most cases.